# Hypothesis testing and standard deviations away from the mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics, standard-deviation

A vice chancellor believes that at her university (UoX) graduates on average have higher salaries that the overall graduate population in the UK. She knows that the average salary of all graduates in the UK is £29,065. She has asked you to test her theory. Let  be the random variable that represents the salary of the UoX graduate population. You choose a sample of 100 UoX graduates and find out their salaries. After collecting your 100 independent and identically distributed (iid) observations, you find that the sample mean is  = £32,512. You know that the variance of the salaries for UoX graduates is  2 = 18790.

Calculate the test statistic and present the result of your test. Is the principal correct that UoX graduates on average have higher slaries compared to the rest of the UK graduates?

I have got a very odd solution for the problem above where the Principal is almost 100% to be correct. The probability of getting that sample result is 251 std deviations above the mean of the null hypothesis, which is impossible. I just want to see if I have got it right. Here is how I got this figure.

Var(UoX Sample Mean) = 18790/100 = 187.9

Assuming the Null Hypothesis is true and UoX graduate salary is no different than the national average of 29065, then the mean of sample mean is 29065.

Therefore, our sample of 100 UoX graduates with mean salary of 32512 is (32512-29065)/squareroot(187.9) = 251 standard deviations away from the mean of Null.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please show your work. That is, how did you calculate that $251$ value?

Comment: Ultimately, the problem is that the information is extremely unrealistic.  The variance of these salaries ought to be closer to $10^9$ than to $1.879\times 10^4.$ The latter is so incredibly small that it could only mean all UoX graduates have been hired into the same position in a government or corporate program at the same basic salary which has barely changed over time. My best guess is that $18790$ is the *standard deviation* of the sample, not the variance.

Comment: If the SD is indeed 18790, then nearly 100% of graduates have a salary between 32k and 33k. Not only would the average be significantly higher than 29065, you'd need about 500 graduates before being likely to find even a *single graduate* with a salary that low.

Comment: @Glen_b Whoops, I meant if the *variance* is indeed 18790. If we assume normally distributed salaries, 99.7% of the distribution falls within 3 SDs of the mean. With 1 SD being 137, nearly all salaries will fall within 411 of the mean.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment:** Following @whuber's suggestion that the sample ***standard deviation*** is $18790,$
here is Minitab output for a one-tailed, one-sample
t test:

```
One-Sample T 

Test of μ = 29065 vs > 29065


  N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean  95% Lower Bound     T      P
100  32512  18790     1879            29392  1.83  0.035
```

The P-value $0.035 < 0.05 = 5\%$ shows that the null
hypothesis $H_0:\mu=29065$ is rejected in favor
of the alternative $H_a: \mu > 29065$ at the 5% level
of significance.

You might want to see if you can get a result
consistent with this one---without a computer.

- What wording in the question led me to do a one-sided test?
- Do you know how to use a printed table of t distributions
  to get a critical value for my test?
- If the alternative had been $H_a: \mu \ne 29065,$
  would we have rejected $H_0$ at the 5% level of signifcance?

*Note:* A considerable risk in doing a test from summarized
data, as here, is that there is no possibility to
look at the data to see if assumptions of the test
are met.